# .htaccess Redirect .net/.org/.info to .com for ANY domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Struggling to work out how to use Apache redirects in .htaccess to redirect ANY domain to it's .com.

e.g.:

- domain1.net >> domain1.com
- domain1.org >> domain1.com
- domain2.net >> domain2.com
- domain2.org >> domain2.com

...

- domainX.net >> domainX.com
- domainX.org >> domainX.com

It needs to work with any domain, so the answer can't include "example.com" etc.

Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)\.(?:net|org)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

But that's not working, it's losing the middle bit of the domain (e.g. "domain1").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work except perhaps the `OR` is breaking it (you have no more `RewriteCond`s).

I would write it as

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?+(.+?)\.(?!com$)[^.]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1.com/$0 [R=301,NE,L]
```